# Is user able to delete CKSubscriptions from Settings?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, cksubscription

I am curious wether user can deny subscriptions after it was accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the settings app you can go to notifications. Your app should be listed there. You can then turn off al messages. The subscription itself won't be disabled. when your app is active you will receive notifications. If you want your subscriptions disabled, then you have to do that from code.

Comment: You have a lot contribution to `cloudkit` tag. Does Apple support you?

Comment: No, I wish... I'm just having a lot of fun with https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao